# Como chamar um som ao clicar no botão android

Tags: java, android, xml

Olá, gostaria de saber como chamar um som mais eficiente?
Pois estou utilizando este método :

```
Button button1;
MediaPlyer mp;
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Teste.this, R.raw.som);
    mp.start();

    }

});
```

e estou com problemas, pois funciona, ao clicar varias vezes tem hora que o som não sai mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uns testes aqui e descobri que esse erro (*error (-19,0)*) acontece quando você cria diversas instâncias do `MediaPlayer` e não chama `release()` em nenhuma delas.

Adicione isso depois de `MediaPlayer.create(...)`:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if(mp != null) {
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }
});
```

O exemplo acima libera o `MediaPlayer` logo depois de terminar de reproduzir o som.

O ideal seria você inicializar esse `MediaPlayer` somente uma vez (no seu `OnCreate`, por exemplo) e reusar a mesma instância até não precisar mais.

Comment: está aparecendo este erro `The method killMediaPlayer() is undefined for the type MediaPlayer` e

Comment: @Rodolfo Dê uma olhada na minha resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Primeiro crie a pasta raw como na imagem abaixo]

Então acrescente esse código:

```
private void playSound() {
   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
   mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Coloquei seu áudio na pasta raw com o nome beep ou altere o ´beep´ pelo nome do seu arquivo no código acima.

Agora é só chamar o método **playSound()** no evento **OnClickListener** do seu botão.